# UX Stack Exchange is out of Beta!

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Just want to let you know that UX.se is officially out of Beta! Thank you for being such an awesome community!

Visual changes: the word "beta" is taken out of site's logo. The footer links to other official SE sites now, instead of to other Beta sites.

Some of you may notice that your privilege level has changed. This is because during the Beta phase, the privilege barrier was lowered. You can see a comprehensive comparison chart [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared).

Again, congrats on the graduation!

Comment: It's a miracle! [Praise the lawd!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jckmU.jpg)

Comment: :( I've lost all of my priveliges. Ah well, just have to keep answering and asking. Wonderful news - really!

Answer (score 5):

Only one answer to that meta "question": **hurray!** :D

Comment: Good thing you took the time to answer, I was about to flag it as "not a real question"... :)

Answer (score 1):

"I've been a member ***since beta days***!", sounds nice to me now.